# Lists inside the cell and output it the same way in php

Tags: php, mysql, list, cell

Is it possible to make a list inside the cell of a table in mysql and outputs it the same way when being retrieved through php?
I've been trying to work it out but I don't know if it's possible.

Sample of this is in my packages table I have a column_name (Inclusions) and in every cell it has lists of data separated by new line. But whenever I retrieve it in php, it displays in one sentence.

Comment: Are you storing multiple data values in a single cell?

Comment: Yes. I store multiple values in a single cell.

Comment: As mentioned in both of the answers, breaking the values down into separate entries and using a `JOIN` statement would be a more efficient way of storing the data.  That way you can easily add or remove data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Barmar is correct, I would suggest a design change in your database.  Instead of listing several values in a single cell, you should have a separate entry for each value and reference it to the list name.

```
    +-----------+   +------------------+
    | List_Name |   | List_Item        |
    |-----------|   |------------------|
    | ID | Name |   | List_ID | Value  |
    | 0  | Frt  |   | 0       | Apple  |
    | 1  | Veg  |   | 1       | Tomato |
    +-----------+   | 1       | Potato |
                    | 0       | Pear   |
                    +------------------+
```

**Querying by List_Name:**

```
    SELECT b.Value
    FROM List_Item b
    JOIN List_Name a ON b.List_ID = a.ID
    WHERE a.Name = 'Frt'
```

**Return all of the values:**

```
    SELECT b.Value
    FROM List_Item b
    JOIN List_Name a ON b.List_ID = a.ID
```

**Return all of the values and order by name:**

```
    SELECT b.Value
    FROM List_Item b
    JOIN List_Name a ON b.List_ID = a.ID
    ORDER BY a.Name ASC | DESC
```

**Return individual values:**

```
    SELECT b.Value
    FROM List_Item b
    JOIN List_Name a ON b.List_ID = a.ID
    WHERE b.Value = 'Apple'
```

This will give you the raw output: `Apple Pear` (you can manually add a line break)

Of course, you can combine this with a loop and you can add a line break with php.

**Edit:** It took me a while to type this, and I did not see the edit on Barmar's answer.

Comment: What if I choose only selected values given in your sample table? Will I be able to separate it from  the others?

Comment: Do you mean selecting just one individual Value (Apple, Tomato, etc.)?  Or do you mean a group of values (all fruits or all vegetables)?

Comment: Yes, selecting values but not all of it in a certain category.

Comment: You would still be able to query each individual entry.  The way a this particular structure works is the category is stored in a separate table than the actual data entries.  If those entries have additional attributes (like date added, etc.) then you can query by those.  If you wanted to return all of the entries, you would `SELECT *`.  If you wanted to order all by category, you would add `ORDER BY a.Name`.

Comment: If you wanted a specific value, you would do `WHERE b.List_Item = 'Apple'`

Comment: I made a mistake, if you wanted to return all of the values you would leave `SELECT b.Value` and get rid of the `WHERE`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) in your PHP code to translate the newlines to HTML `<br>` markup.

```
echo nl2br($row['inclusions']);
```

However, it probably would be better for you to normalize the database. Lists should not be in a single cell, they should be in a relation table. Then you can use a `JOIN` to find all the related values, and display them in whatever way is appropriate, such as in a `<table>` or `<ul>`.